# Logback system property from command line

Tags: logging, logback, logback-classic

I am trying to -D the location of the logback.xml file on the java command line running on a windows machine:

```
PS C:\testexecclient> java -DpropertyFolder=c:\testexecclient -Dlogback.configurationFile=c:\testexecclient\logback.xml
-jar testexecclient-1.0.jar
```

The logback.configurationFile property key is causing an issue. Java doesn't seem to like the X.Y format for a property key on a windows machine. It says it can't find the main class. I remove that property key/value and all is good, but I have no logging to a file.

What is the appropriate property key for logback when trying to run on windows machine ?

thanks

Comment: this issue is related to trying to run the java application in powershell. Don't have time to figure out the issue. Runs fine from the DOS prompt.

Comment: At least add a sample of the error message so other people can take advantage of your experience.

Comment: fair enough....issuing the command above via powershell, I get the following output:  Error: Could not find or load main class .configurationFile=c:.testexecclient.logback.xml

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
java -DpropertyFolder=c:\testexecclient -D"logback.configurationFile=c:\testexecclient\logback.xml"
-jar testexecclient-1.0.jar
```

Note the quotes.